# No puedo usar pyperclip en Goggle Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colab

Intenté comenzar a usar el módulo *pyperclip* con *Google Colaboratory*, con el siguiente código:

```
!pip install pyperclip

import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('Hello, world!')
pyperclip.paste()
```

Sin embargo, me aparece el siguiente error:

> ```
> Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist->packages (1.8.1)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> PyperclipException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-8-a060f90a4ff2> in <module>()
>      2 
>      3 import pyperclip
> ----> 4 pyperclip.copy('Hello, world!')
>      5 pyperclip.paste()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py in __call__(self, >*args, **kwargs)
>    334 
>    335         def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 336             raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)
>    337 
>    338         if PY2:
>
> PyperclipException: 
>    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
>    For more information, please visit >https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error
> ```

Comment: Lo primero que está en negrita te está indicando que pyperclip ya está instalado, te recomiendo encarecidamente aprender inglés si quieres dedicarte a programar. En cuanto a los últimos errores, el enlace que te ponen a la documentación te explica exactamente lo que está pasando y cómo solucionarlo. El SO que está corriendo ese código no tiene un mecanismo de copy/paste instalado, pyperclip requiere que el SO tenga un portapapeles para poder funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario, le comento que mi problema principal, es que estoy aprendiendo a programar, con el inglés no tengo problema, con los tecnicismos de la programación en inglés (y en español) en verdad tengo problemas, y pues como lo digo, estoy aprendiendo. le agradecería que me ayudara a mejorar. En cuanto al enlace, señala que ese error generalmente aparece en Linux, y yo no estoy usando Linux (aún así, intenté poner en práctica la solución del enlace y no me funcionó), agradecería que alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene porque estás usando **Google Colaboratory**. Realmente da igual el sistema operativo que tengas, porque estás lanzando el código en una **máquina virtual**, es decir en un ordenador que tiene google, **no en tu ordenador**.

Actualmente el paquete `Pyperclip` no tiene soporte para Google Colaboratory, por lo que no se puede usar ya que las máquinas virtuales de Google no tiene la función copy/paste.

La solución es que **ejecutes el código en tu propio ordenador!**